# How to handle login + FB login at the same time with django-allauth module?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

Well.. I started to create simple app. Following official doc of Django, I created auth logic in separate app with name `users`, like this:

**users/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('profile/', views.redirect_to_user_profile, name='redirect-user-profile'),
    re_path('profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.UserProfileView.as_view(), name='user-profile'),
    path('register/', views.UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='user-register'),
```

**users/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.


def redirect_to_user_profile(request):
    url = f'/users/profile/{request.user.id}'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to=url)


class UserProfileView(generic.DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'user_profile.html'


class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = '/users/login'
```

Everything was fine, so I decided to extent basic Django user, to add profile image for example (and more fields later) like this:

**users/models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.URLField()

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) # Still don't know how, but next rows create ProfileUser when User is created
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            ProfileUser.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profileuser.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"
```

Still working fine. Then I decided to add FB login, after some researh I found django-allauth module, following it documentation and add one row in users/urls.py:

```
path('fb/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

It also working, But here comes the problem currently I have two separate modules for authorization:

**Basic django User** auth logic:

[image]

And **django-allauth** auth logic:

[image]

How to handle this (best way):

**What I think:** To use only Django-allauth, but is there a way to extend it with additional ProfileUser, like extend it now with Django User?

Answer (score 1):

Using only Django-allauth is a good assumption. 
The way to extend Django User is by something like that:

```
class ProfileUser(AbstractUser):
    profile_image = models.URLField()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'profile_user'
```

However, change like that could enforce to make [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/) from the beginning. Or trying to fix them manually. This is because of `auth` app migrations are done as a second just after `contenttypes`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on @artusiep answer and a lot of research, I found that the best way is to use one of them, but not both at the same time. Also found very good tutorial about both implementation [here](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial-custom-user-model/)